# Error catching and File IO

Tags: java, file-io, exception

I have an assignment where I need to write a while loop code block that contains a `try­catch` statement. The `try` block retrieves each line from an input file, and invokes an `isValid` method I created to check if the format is correct, passing to it the line from the file. If there are no more lines to parse, `runProgram` is set to `false`, the while loop terminates. The `catch` block will catch an exception that I made. So far I have

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     File file;
     Scanner inputFile;
     String fileName;

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
     fileName = scan.nextLine();

     boolean runProgram = true;
     while(runProgram)
     {
        try
        {
           // for loop to check each line of my file
           // invoke isValid
           // Check if it's the last line in the file, and end program if so
        }
        catch(BankAccountException e)
        {
           System.out.println("Account Exception. Do you wish to quit? y/n");
           String quit = scan.nextLine();
           if(quit.equals("y"))
              runProgram = false;
           else
              runProgram = true;
        }
     }
  }
```

I just have no idea how to open a file, check the next line, use my `isValid` method (which is just a `StringTokenizer` that checks for the correct format), and closes when it reaches the end of the file.
Here is my `isValid` method:

```
   private static boolean isValid(String accountLine) throws BankAccountException
   {
      StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(accountLine, ";");
      boolean valid = true;
      if(strTok.countTokens() == 2)
      {
         if(strTok.nextToken().length() == 10)
         {
            if(!strTok.nextToken().matches(".*[0-9].*"))
            {
               valid = true;
            }
         }
      }
      else
         valid = false;
      return valid;
   }
```

I also have a question with the above method. If I call `.nextToken()` twice, am I right in expecting the first iteration to deal with the first token, and the second to deal with the second? Or will they both just check the first token?

Comment: Look at [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) , [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) and [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). They should be able to achieve what you want. Otherwise explore the IO package. The [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) is also useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get you started.

```
try {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/File")));
  String currLine;
  while ((currLine = reader.readLine()) != null) { // returns null at EOF
      if (!isValid(currLine)) throw new BankAccountException();
  }
} catch (BankAccountException e) {
  // same
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```